# Apache jmeter dashboard report on jmeter v5 showing different min and max value for 1 user but different runcount

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Apache JMeter dashboard report on JMeter v5 showing different min and max values for 1 user for different runcount.
For example:-

```
for 1 user and 1 run count min and max is:-26.98,26.98
for 1 user and 2 run count min and max is:-29.98,35.19
```

How can min and max values be different for 1 user for different runcounts?

Comment: Would need more information. When you say "1 run" and "2 run" do you mean "Test run 1" and "Test run 2"? If so, how many iterations does the test complete? 
By "JMeter dashboard" do you mean the HTML report or an "Aggregate Report"?  
Can you provide a screenshot of the report you are referring to? 

I suspect that "Test run 1" and "Test run 2" run multiple iterations resulting in differing min/max times ... but without more information it is too difficult to say.

Comment: We run each testcase 3 times. For example:- let's say we have testcase name TC_001,we ran it for 10,50,100 users. we run it thrice for 10 users, thrice for 50 users, thrice for 100 users. these 3 times we called as run count 1, run count 2, run count 3. By "JMeter dashboard"  i mean HTML report. In jmeter Version 3 when we ran any testcase for 1 user the min and max value in html report remains same. when i ran same testcase on JMeter Version 5 the min and max values differs. when there is only one user how come be min and max value different.

Comment: If it is different between JMeter versions I would suspect that it was a bug that has been fixed ... You could read version bugs/changes [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have one more doubt i.e. While recording the script on JMeter V5 i am getting a request that has type as :-OPTION. like we get [get, post, patch, put, delete] same as  i am getting option type request. please let me know what would the possible reasons for getting a request of OPTION type.

Comment: The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain identified by the Request-URI. This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval. [link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: For more information, I am getting the option type request only when i am recording the script through JMeter V5. but when i am normally browsing the url and i opened dev tool bar simultaneously to check whether i am getting this request or not , so by dev tool bar i am not getting option type request. so My question is why i am getting this option type request while recording the script through jmeter V5. what would be the reason for this?

Comment: Not sure on the reason for this without actually having the script to play with... Could it be that this is a URL that is redirected elsewhere?